# Parameter passing in functions in C language?

Tags: c

Below is the code(unchanged) of a question I encountered while solving hackerrank questions:

But i couldnot understand 3 lines which i have marked as number 1,2 and 3 in the below code.

As the program flows from main to func's

Lets look at 3 first:

We are passing a function name lexicographic_sort as one of the parameter to string_sort function.

Now lets have a look at 1 and 2:

In function string_sort

lexicographic_sort is passed as int (cmp_func)(const char a, const char b)*

**1st doubt**: what is cmp_func, it is not defined anywhere, is it a sytem defined function?

**2nd doubt**: we are not passing any parameters which would go into char* a, char* b. What would go to their values?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    #include <string.h>

 1. int lexicographic_sort(const char* a, const char* b) {

    }
    
    int lexicographic_sort_reverse(const char* a, const char* b) {
    
    }
    
    int sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters(const char* a, const char* b) {
        
    }
    
    int sort_by_length(const char* a, const char* b) {
    
    }

 2. void string_sort(char** arr,const int len,int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b))

    {
        
    
    }


    int main() 
    {
        int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
  
    char** arr;
    arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
  
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        *(arr + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", *(arr + i));
        *(arr + i) = realloc(*(arr + i), strlen(*(arr + i)) + 1);
    }
  
    

 3. string_sort(arr, n, lexicographic_sort);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    
        string_sort(arr, n, lexicographic_sort_reverse);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%s\n", arr[i]); 
        printf("\n");
    
        string_sort(arr, n, sort_by_length);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%s\n", arr[i]);    
        printf("\n");
    
        string_sort(arr, n, sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%s\n", arr[i]); 
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: This code won't compile.

Comment: Hey Harvey, it is not complete code,
It is a outline of Hacker rank's question using which we ll have to fill.
But then I did not understand what they are passing in the lines 1, 2 and 3

Comment: `cmp_func` is the name of the 3rd parameter and its type is "pointer to a function which accepts two `char` pointers and returns `int`", just as `len` is the name of the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Hey Groo, Then what is char* a and char* b  which is being passed to cmp_func?

Comment: at code number 3, we are not passing any parameters with the function, so what values would a and b take?

Comment: at 3, inside the string_sort(), you can call cmp_func() with whatever you want. Ergo, your question of what values a and b take is nonsensical.

Comment: understood, thank you a lot guy
All of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the `string_sort` function is to sort an array of strings in a particular order - exactly what that order *is* depends on the function designator that's passed as the third argument.

`cmp_func` is a pointer to a function - the declaration reads as

```
      cmp_func                                -- cmp_func
     *cmp_func                                --   is a pointer to
    (*cmp_func)(                            ) --   a function taking
    (*cmp_func)(            a               ) --     parameter a
    (*cmp_func)(          * a               ) --       is a pointer to
    (*cmp_func)(const char* a               ) --       const char
    (*cmp_func)(const char* a,             b) --     parameter b
    (*cmp_func)(const char* a,           * b) --       is a pointer to
    (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b) --       const char
int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b) --   returning int
```

When you call `string_sort`, you pass a function designator as the third argument - in this case, the name of one of your comparison functions.  `string_sort` then *calls* that function as part of its operation, and uses that to determine how to order the strings in the array.

This is probably best explained by example.  Let's assume `string_sort` is implemented as a plain old bubble sort (in reality it probably wouldn't be, but it works for illustrative purposes):

```
void string_sort( char **arr, const int len, int (*cmp_func)(const char *a, const char *b ) )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++ )
  {
    for ( j = i+1; j < len; j++ )
    {
      if ( cmp_func( arr[i], arr[j] ) > 0 )
      {
        swap( &arr[i], &arr[j] ); // imagine this being implemented elsewhere
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The order in which strings are sorted depends on the comparison function pointed to by `cmp_func`.  The normal protocol is that the comparison function will return a positive value if the first argument is "greater" than the second, a negative value if the first argument is "less" than the second, and 0 if the two values are "equal".  We will swap strings if the first argument is "greater" than the second, otherwise we leave them as-is.

What "greater", "less", and "equal" mean depends on what function was passed to `string_sort` for `cmp_func`.  Suppose `arr[i] == "foo"` and `arr[j] == "bar"`.  Here's how they would (likely) be ordered for each of the different comparison functions (based on the function names):

```
cmp_func                               Return value    String order
--------                               ------------    ------------
lexicographic_sort                               >0    "bar", "foo"
lexicographic_sort_reverse                       <0    "foo", "bar"
sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters            <0    "foo", "bar"
sort_by_length                                    0    "foo", "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `string_sort`

```
void string_sort( char** arr, const int len, int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b) );
```

declared as having three parameters. The first one is of the type `char **`. The second one of the type `const int`. And the third one of the type `int (*)(const char* a, const char* b)` that is the third parameter is a pointer to function that has two parameters of the type `const char *` and the return type `int`.  This parameter is used within the function `string_sort` to compare two strings.

Then the function `string_sort` is called like

```
string_sort( arr, n, lexicographic_sort );
```

where the third argument is the function `lexicographic_sort_reverse` declared like

```
int lexicographic_sort_reverse(const char* a, const char* b) {

}
```

that has the required type of the third parameter of the function `string_sort`. The function designator `lexicographic_sort` used as the third argument is implicitly converted to pointer to the function.

So

> 1st doubt: what is cmp_func, it is not defined anywhere, is it a sytem
> defined function?

`cmp_func` is the name pf the parameter of the function `string_sort`. In a function declaration that at the same time is a function definition names of parameters must be present.

The declaration of the function string_sort that is not a definition could look like

```
void string_sort( char**, const int, int ( * )(const char*, const char*));
```

That is names of parameters are not required.

You could imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
string_sort(arr, n, lexicographic_sort);

//...

void string_sort( /*char** arr,const int len,int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b) */)
{
    char **arr1 = arr; // I changed the name of the parameter to arr1
    const int len = n;
    int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b) = lexicographic_sort;
    //...
}
```

> 2nd doubt: we are not passing any parameters which would go into char*
> a, char* b. What would go to their values?

It is the function `string_sort` calls within itself the function `lexicographic_sort` thyat was assigned to the parameter `cmp_func` passing to it strings pointed to by the parameter arr to compare them during sorting. You need to investigate the body of the function `string_sort`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1st doubt: what is cmp_func, it is not defined anywhere, is it a sytem defined function?

`cmp_function` is not a system function,It is a pointer to function in C, it is way to pass a function to another function (can be used as custom sort comparator as in this case or as callback in other use cases)

For the function
`void string_sort(char** arr,const int len,int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b))`

It has 3 arguments:

`arr`: pointer to pointer to char

`len`: int

`cmp_funct`: pointer to function that has 2 arguments both are `const char*` and returns int.

so when you call `string_sort` you have to pass to it in third arguments a pointer to function(name of the function or & before it, it won't matter) that matches these arguments criteria as the case in `int lexicographic_sort_reverse(const char* a, const char* b)` and  `sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters`.

> 2nd doubt: we are not passing any parameters which would go into char*
> a, char* b. What would go to their values?

I think this question is answered now, as they are not arguments to the function, they describe the arguments to the function pointer that is passed.

I really recommend that you read more about pointer to functions, there a lot of tutorials on it on the internet.